# Onclick to radio button set new session

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I  have some radio buttons and I want to set `$_SESSION` with the value of the radio button when selected.

What is the best approach to do this.

- Radio 1 on click set `$_SESSION['radio'] = 1`
- Radio 2 on click set `$_SESSION['radio'] = 2`
- Radio 3 on click set `$_SESSION['radio'] = 3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <form>
        Radio 1<input type="radio" name="radio" onClick="set_session('radio1');" >
        Radio 2<input type="radio" name="radio" onClick="set_session('radio2');" >
        Radio 3<input type="radio" name="radio" onClick="set_session('radio3');" >
    </form>
    <script>
    function set_session(radio)
    {
        if(radio != '')
        {
            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'session.php?radio='+radio,

                    success: function(response) {
                            if(response!= null) 
                            {
                                alert(response+' Session Set');
                            }
                        }
                });
        }
    }
    </script>
```

in your session.php  file

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['radio']) && !empty($_POST['radio']))
{
    session_start();
    if($_POST['radio'] == 'radio1')
    {
        $radio1 = $_SESSION[$_POST['radio']];
        echo $radio1;
    }
    else if($_POST['radio'] == 'radio2')
    {
        $radio2 = $_SESSION[$_POST['radio']];
        echo $radio2;
    }
    else
    {
        $radio3 = $_SESSION[$_POST['radio']];
        echo $radio3;
    }
    die;
}
?>
```